# Angular, Error al iterar con NgFor

Tags: array, angular

He leído sobre el asunto pero como soy novato en Angular, NodeJS y Typescript no logro llevar la solución a mi código. Como detalle, la base de datos (Mysql) la tengo en un servidor y puedo verla por consola y trabajarla con una aplicación cliente (Postman) pero cuando trato de iterar me arroja un error, por lo que el documento desde donde trato de iterar debe estar mal programado. Y suponiendo que lo que quiero mostrar por pantalla es el campo "rut" que aparece en mi documento-list.component.html, cómo debería hacerlo?

El error:

```
trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed.
```

Y el error comienza aquí:

```
DOCUMENTO-LIST.COMPONENT.HTML
<div class="col-md-4" *ngFor="let documento of documentos">
    <div class="card text-center">
        <div class="card-header">
            {{documento.rut}}
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

El siguiente código llama a un servicio que llama a un modelo que supongo, debe estar mal (posee el siguiente código: export interface Documento {rut?: number}) y me provoca el error porque si en vez de `this.documentos = res` utilizo `console.log = res`, la consola me lee correctamente los datos de la tabla.

```
DOCUMENTO-LIST.COMPONENT.TS
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { DocumentosService } from '../../services/documentos.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-documento-list',
  templateUrl: './documento-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./documento-list.component.scss']
})
export class DocumentoListComponent implements OnInit {

  documentos: any = [];

  constructor(private documentosService: DocumentosService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.documentosService.getDocumentos().subscribe(
      res => {
        this.documentos = res;
      },
      err => console.error(err)
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: Hola y bienvenido! Lo que te está diciendo el error es que al **NgFor** le llega un objeto y no un array o un iterable. Lo que podes hacer primero es ver como te llega la respuesta del servicio con simplemente `console.log(res)` con eso validas que te esté llegando lo que esperas. Otra cosa a tener en cuenta: *res* seguramente llega en formato JSON y quizás dentro tenga un array, deberías igualar tu variable *documentos* al array del JSON, algo así como `documentos = res.documentos`

Comment: Gracias por responder. Lo intentaré por la tarde porque ahora ya no estoy en el computador.

Comment: Hola. Como comenta @andres, lo que estás recibiendo no es un arreglo, es un objeto. Con un `console.log` en tu subscribe deberías de ser capaz de visualizar la estructura de la respuesta.

Comment: Si pasas el texto de lo que devuelve el `console.log(res)` podemos ver la estructura de la respuesta del servicio y de esta manera darte una mejor respuesta. No hace falta que muestres los datos en sí, lo que mas importa es la estructura del JSON.

Comment: Puede mostrar que te aparece cuando pones {{ documentos }} en tu html :

Comment: No te da error el editor? al querer asignar this.documentos = res---> usas VSC como editor ? porque el mismo editor no deberia permitirte asignar un objeto a un array que te da res.length

Answer (score 0):

Lo mejor seria o hacer que backend mande un array o transformarlo dentro del flujo observable de la peticion http del servicio que uses para traer los datos... pero esto serviria en todo caso para hacerlo en el componente:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.documentosService.getDocumentos()
  .subscribe((res: any) => {

      let result = [];
      
      let keys = Object.keys(res);
        keys.forEach(function(key){
            result.push(res[key]);
        });

      this.documentos = result;
    },
    err => console.error(err)
  );
}
```

la recomendacion si back no puede modificar los datos seria aplicar la conversion aqui descrita a tu metodo de carga de datos desde back.